# Drawbacks to line-height without unit?

Tags: accessibility, css

Are there any drawbacks(browser/device inconsistency...) in specifing line height without unit?

Example:

```
body {

    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: I think it will not work, i mean browser can't recognize.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In most cases, it's actually better to use unitless line-height - see

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height - see the notes where they show an example

Of course, there are exceptions. The first one that comes to mind is when you have a block element with a *known* `height` and with *one line of text in it* and you want to center that line of text vertically - I find that the easiest way to do that is to use a `line-height` that's equal to the `height` of the block element.

---

*[Just in case, for anybody who doesn't know what's the deal with unitless `line-height`.]*

Suppose you have an element with `font-size: 14px`. It doesn't matter where it was set, whether it's inherited or not, if you set it yourself or it came from the user agent stylesheet. The element has `font-size: 14px`.

Now, if you set, let's say `line-height: 1.5` for the same element, this will be translated into pixels as **1.5 * 14px = 21px**. So your computed `line-height` will be `21px`.

Comment: Thanks Ana, but what I am asking is, is there any accessibility issue with using line height without declared unit.

Comment: As far as I know, for accessibility reasons it's recommended to use unitless line-heights between 1.3 and 1.6.

Comment: +1 and another vote that unitless line-height is fine. Techniques for WCAG 2.0: [C21: Specifying line spacing in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C21.html) recommends 1.5 - 2.0.

Comment: Interestingly, the link mentioned by @steveax now uses `150%` (%) rather than `1.5` (unitless). Perhaps it was felt that a raw number was less clear. The unitless form is part of the spec ("number" is their term for a unitless value), with no indication of disfavor.  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height