# Same REM measurement results in different pixel values

Tags: html, css

I am using REM values. At smaller screen sizes my base font-size is equivalent to 9 pixels:

```
html {
    font-size: 56.25%;
}
```

(16px x 56.25% = 9px)

I have noticed that Chrome calculates the pixel values differently depending on what is being measured. For example:

I have a `<header>` element. The height of which is decided by the line-height: 6.3rem (6.3 x 9px = 56.7px).

```
header { line-height: 6.3rem }
```

Chrome calculates this as 57px.

However, if I change the code to

```
header { height: 6.3rem; }
```

Chrome calculates this as 57.69px.

If I have a nav positioned absolutely just under the header:

```
nav { position: absolute; top: 6.3rem; }
```

Chrome calculates the top distance as 56.7px

These differences are proving a pain as the header and nav have different background colours and a border and Chrome is renduring these sub-pixel differences.

Why would a browser render the same measurement differently?

JSFiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/79tbdovq/1/

In Chrome there is a sub-pixel border-bottom displayed, that shouldn't display. Although for some reason in JSFiddle it works fine.

Comment: Did you try to add `box-size:border` ?

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is that the same rem value results in different pixel measurements.

Comment: The reason is subpixel rounding. For this reason, px units are generally preferred over rem or em.

Answer (score 1):

The behave of line-height is quite trick... ([similar subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695333/why-does-unitless-line-height-behave-differently-from-percentage-or-em-in-this-e))

Calcul you made is good but even if you write `line-height: 56.7px;` it will show `line-height: 56px` in Chrome tools.

Anyway, if you want a work around working with height and box border:

```
header {
  height: 6.3rem;              /* ADDED */
  line-height: 6.3rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;     /* ADDED */
}
```

### DEMO

```css
html, body {
    font-size: 56.25%;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 6.3rem;             /* ADDED */
  line-height: 6.3rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;     /* ADDED */
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6.3rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header>Logo and hamburger</header>
<nav>Nav list</nav>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why three (line-height, height and absolute) exactly the same measurements results in three different pixel measurements.

Comment: Did you read the similar subject I put? I was not going to copy/paste huge explication of main answer

Comment: It's not just line-height that gives a different result, but also position:absolute gives a different result to height. I haven't tested but does this mean that padding, margin and other measurements in REM result in different pixel measurements.